# C# Issue: program terminates itself when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, termination

I'm making a C# console application for my college course and I've got an issue where I (or anybody else on the course) don't know what's wrong. In fact the tutor's not sure why it's happening. 
I'll show you part of the code to see if anyone can help. 
Probably a good idea to mention that I'm new to C# and programming in general.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userName = GetName();
        int gradelevel = level();
        double random1 = 0;
        double random2 = 0;
        int userChoice = menu();
        int numberofquestions = 0; 
        string Message;
        int userScore = 0;

        do
        {
            if ((gradelevel == 1) && (userChoice == 1))//ADDITION LEVEL 1
            {

                generateSingleDigit(ref random1, ref random2);
                double userAnswer = additionQuestion(ref random1, ref random2);
                double Correctanswer = random1 + random2;
                Message = checkAnswer(userAnswer, Correctanswer);

                if (userAnswer == Correctanswer)
                {
                    generatePositiveResponse();
                    userScore++;
                }
                else
                {
                    int numberofAttempts = 1;

                    do
                    {
                        generateNegativeResponse();
                        userAnswer = additionQuestion(ref random1, ref random2);
                        Message = checkAnswer(userAnswer, Correctanswer);
                        numberofAttempts++;
                    } while ((numberofAttempts < 3) && (Message == "Incorrect"));
                    Console.WriteLine("The correct answer is {0}", Correctanswer);
                }
            }


                numberofquestions++;
        } while (numberofquestions <= 9);
           percentage(ref userScore); `
```

The issue I'm having is that once the user has completed the 10 questions, the results from the percentage method briefly flash up and then the application closes itself. No "Press any key to continue" that I've seen in other applications I've made.

I would really appreciate any help on this. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `Console.ReadLine()` statement at the very end of your program?  When you run it, are you running through Visual Studio?

Comment: Aren't you missing Console.ReadKey()

Comment: I'm running it through the debug console through Visual Studio. I'm not sure what you mean by having a 'Console.ReadLine()' statement. same goes for ReadKey().

Comment: "In fact the tutor's not sure why it's happening". Should probably look for a new tutor?

Comment: I don't get a choice in who my tutor is, it's just whoever the college has hired.

Comment: Either add Console.ReadKey() or start the app from VS with Ctrl+F5

Comment: @Alex - Starting the app from within VS without debugging will result in the same behavior.

Comment: @Tim - I'm not sure about the specific case that failed for you, however starting the application without debugging always prompts for keypress in my environment. Regardless of that, ReadKey() is better approach.

Comment: @Alex - I stand corrected; without debugging will leave the window open until you press a key.

Comment: Can I ask another question? As it relates to this bit of code. The other issue I'm having is the numberofquestions part at the end. It's supposed to ask 10 questions but when I try `while(numberofquestions == 10)` is only allows the user to do 1 question, when it should do 10.

Comment: It should be `!= 10`, because you want to loop every time your number of questions is not yet at 10, and exit when it is at 10. == 10 means "If the variable is 10, then do an other loop iteration"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `Console.ReadLine()` at the end, the window will stay open until you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key. Otherwise, once it's completed, it'll close the command window.

Comment: Technically, it'll wait until you press the `Enter` key.

Comment: Fair point. Tim beat me to the answer anyway in the comments.

Comment: I've put that in, and it fixes that issue, now I need to make so that the results for all of the different menu options don't show at the same time.

Comment: You may need to restructure some of the code if you don't want to display certain parts. Use 'Console.ReadLine()' every time you want to pause, and potentially add in the line from the Joel Coehoorn's reply to tell the user to press 'Enter' to continue.

Comment: I've put in a readline() at the end of each bit (when I say bit I mean the part of the code I've put in the question repeats itself for other purposes for subtraction, multiplication and division questions) and that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're missing a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your program.  When you run a console app in Visual Studio it's normal behavior for the window to be closed once the program finishes, unless there's code (like a `Console.ReadLine()`) to keep the program running.

IF you ran the program directly from a DOS window, the program would still exit but the window would stay open, you'd just be back at the command prompt again.

Answer (score 1):

> No "Press any key to continue" that I've seen in other applications I've made.

Why would there be? That doesn't happen unless you write code to make it happen:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Visual Studio used to put code to do that into the default template of C++ programs, but I've never seen it for C#, and even with the old C++ programs you could see the code that caused this.